# flex 4 context menu removed with actionscript code

Tags: javascript, flex4, contextmenu

i have some code that i couldn't understand its behavior, will appreciate any explanation and fix :

when using this code i managed to remove flex 4 context menu, but when removing the alerts the context menu returns to right click... strange behavior !!!!

```
<script language="javascript">
    function click(e) {
        if (navigator.appName == 'Netscape' && e.which == 3) {
            //alert("no right click please")
            return false;
        }
        else {
            if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer' && event.button == 2) {
                //alert("no right click please")
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    document.onmousedown = click
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is quite simple: the alerts, being modal, forces flash into the background and breaks the callstack. Once this happen, flash cannot regain control after you dismiss the alertbox, because your original rigthclick mousevent has now expired.

Comment: ok, so the right click still works even with return false, how could i break the callstack without an alert in this code, or cancel the right click without alert, i have already tried many examples, non have workd with flex4 player 10, thanks for the explanation

Comment: You can't, the only way is to show a modal box like alert or confirm